# can we use if condition for compare 2 dates and display the row in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 dates column, one is current date and the one is user define date, I have to display the specific row when the user define date is 2days greater than current date.
In the below code I try to display the row, when both dates are equal. But I don't know how display the row in sql.

I have following Columns,

- `Rid`
- `DateTime` (User define date and time)
- `Reminder`
- `Description`
- `CRDateTime` (current date and time)

I have to set 3 condition.

1. if both dates are equal means that should be display,
2. if DateTime is 2 days before CRDate means I have to display that row,
3. if DateTime is 1 day before the CRdate means I have to display that row.

```
declare DateTime as datetime1;

select RId if CAST (DateTime as date) =CAST (@CRDateTime as date)
```

Comment: Which System are you using? MySQL, MSSQL or something else?

Comment: What you typed won't compile. There's no `datetime1` type and the `SELECT` query isn't using a table.

Answer (score 1):

The `IF...ELSE` statement is a control-flow statement that allows you to execute or skip a statement block based on a specified condition.

For example:

```
   IF Boolean_expression
   BEGIN
      -- Statement block executes when the Boolean expression is TRUE
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      -- Statement block executes when the Boolean expression is FALSE
   END
```

If you want to check something in your SQL Statements you should use the `where` clause.

It could be looking like:

```
SELECT * FROM `[YOUR_TABLE_NAME]` WHERE `DateTime` = `CRDateTime`
```

If you want to check the date in a 2 Day decade you can use the SQL `DATEADD` Function.

It lookse like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, +1, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;
```

Resault of this code is `2017/08/26`

In your case it looks like this:

```
SELECT RId where DATEADD(day, +2, DateTime) = CRDateTime
```

--- EDIT SECTION: ---

EDIT 1:

All in one you can use this code here:

```
SELECT RId WHERE 
`DateTime` = `CRDateTime` OR
DATEADD(day, +1, DateTime) = CRDateTime OR
DATEADD(day, +2, DateTime) = CRDateTime
```

Comment: This query is working. But it is not show the values. It shows only column name.How to solve it?

Comment: Try first this one here ```SELECT * FROM [ENTER_HERE_YOUR_TABLE_NAME] WHERE 
`DateTime` = `CRDateTime` OR
DATEADD(day, +1, DateTime) = CRDateTime OR
DATEADD(day, +2, DateTime) = CRDateTime``` in your query you only select the `RId`. That's Probably why.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you basically want to show all the records with in range of 2 days.

```
 SELECT RId, DateTime, Reminder, Description, CRDateTime 
 WHERE CRDateTime BETWEEN DATETIME AND DATEADD(day, +2, DateTime)
```

Or you may try this

```
 SELECT RId, DateTime, Reminder, Description, CRDateTime 
 WHERE DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -2, CRDateTime) AND CRDateTime
```

Comment: this comment executed. But it is not show the data. It shows only the column name? How to resolve it

Comment: add your required column in select statement, updated please check now.

Comment: Actually I add my required column. But my doubt is I do not get the data which was store in the db. It shows only the columns names

Comment: @Gaayathri: try this, updated my ans in second part.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear. I assume the actual question is how to filter a table's rows between two dates.

Filtering in SQL (in any product) is the job of the `WHERE` clause, not IF. You can use the `BETWEEN` clause to select values in a range.

If both the table field and the query parameter are `date` variables, the query is easy :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    RId int PRIMARY KEY,
    DateField date,
    INDEX IX_Table1_Date (DateField)
)


declare @dateParam date='20190801';

SELECT RId
FROM table1
WHERE DateField BETWEEN dateadd(day,-2,@dateParam) AND @DateParam
```

This query will take advantage of the `IX_Table1_Date` index to speed up the search. Typically, applying any kind of function on a table field prevents the query engine from using any index that includes that field simply because the values stored in the index have no relation to the function's result.

If you use the date parameter to be the current date, just assign `GETDATE()` to it.

```
declare @dateParam date=GETDATE();
```

If the field isn't a date, you can cast it to date and still get a fast range query, because the query engine is fast enough to convert the cast to a range query.

```
SELECT RId
FROM table1
WHERE cast(DateField as date) BETWEEN dateadd(day,-2,@dateParam) AND @DateParam
```

If `DateField` is *not* a date-related type, eg it's a varchar, a) that's a serious bug and b) the server won't be able to use any indexes.

Casting the parameter values won't affect performance as they actual values are calculated before the query starts executing. The query becomes quite noisy though :

```
declare @dateParam datetime='20190801'


SELECT RId
FROM table1
WHERE cast(DateField as date) 
       BETWEEN dateadd(day,-2,cast(@dateParam as date)) AND cast(@DateParam as date)
```

That's why it's better to use the *correct* type for parameters